# Azure DevOps get Deployment Agent status during release

Tags: azure-devops, release, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to get the status of agents in a deployment pool at release time.
The use case is I have 2 servers with shared disk, I want the release to run on one server only. I have two Deployment groups that run based on a custom condition:

```
eq(variables['DeployGroupSelector'], '1')
```

With a job that runs prior to those that will determine the value of the DeployGroupSelector var, essentially a case statement.

In the job that sets the var, I'm trying to reach out to the Azure DevOps REST API:

```
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$($poolId)/agents?api-version=5.1"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Headers $headers -Verbose
write-host "Output: $response"
$status = ($response.value | where {$_.name -eq $($env:primaryPoolName)}).status
if($status -eq "online")
{
    Write-Output("##vso[task.setvariable variable=DeployGroupSelector;]1")
}
else
{
    Write-Output("##vso[task.setvariable variable=DeployGroupSelector;]2")
}
```

For the group containing the script above the "Allow scripts access to the OAuth token" box is checked.

When I run this powershell locally using a PAT it returns data. When I run the release in ADO, it hits the service, but returns an empty data set:

```
2019-10-07T14:16:18.8942915Z VERBOSE: GET https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxx/_apis/distributedtask/pools/13/agents?api-version=5.1 with 0-byte payload
2019-10-07T14:16:19.3235204Z VERBOSE: received 22-byte response of content type application/json
2019-10-07T14:16:19.9626359Z VERBOSE: Content encoding: utf-8
2019-10-07T14:16:19.9835101Z Output: @{count=0; value=System.Object[]}
```

I have tried giving the "Project Collection Build Service Accounts" group read access to pools and groups, I even tried bumping it up to user. I tried adding the build service accounts group to release administrators. I even tried using the old url format just in case.

Added picture of data returned from powershell:

[image]

UPDATE: Just to further rule out an issue with how I was using the token, I added a second powershell task to the task group in question. This script hits a different segment of the AzDO Rest API (below). This successfully gets a response. So the OAuth token is working, it just doesn't seem to have access to the entire API.

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/$($project)/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Headers $headers -Verbose
write-host "Output: $($response)"
```

Response: `Output: @{value=System.Object[]; count=10}`

Comment: From where you get the `$pooId?`

Comment: I went to the Deployment Pools in the UI, selected the pool, and got the ID from the URI. It can also be queried through the rest api.

Comment: I asked because there are also agents queues with different id and the api its for agent pools. I can not reproduce your issue, in my release I got the agents in the response.

Comment: Can you upload here a screenshot of your PowerShell script results with the same URL the release executed?

Comment: Added picture..

Comment: Please share the PowerShell code (you can hide the organization from the url..)

Comment: The powershell shared above is from my release. I ran the same script locally with one exception; I use a Basic token with a PAT instead of a Bearer token.

Comment: What is the pool id when you run it locally?

Comment: 13 which would be the same pool when I run it via the release. I know there is no issue with the variables being substituted into the URI because when I click the link shown in the log above it shows me data. That would be using my PAT, so it would seem to be an issue of the Release Token not having the appropriate scope to view the deployment agents.

Comment: I added some more details about a second task using the same token that does work so the issue cannot be with how I'm retrieving the token.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the System_AccessToken variable, did you also enable the "Allow scripts to access OAuth token" checkbox in the agent job? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#systemaccesstoken This link shows where it is in build but you'll find it at the bottom of the Agent Job panel in release. If that's not checked, that may be why you're getting an empty response.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I enabled this.

Comment: Have you tried passing in a PAT that has pool read access to try and isolate if it's a permissions issue? I know that sometimes certain APIs in AzDO require more permissions than just the PAT passed in from a release (like certain distributed task APIs or the extension API).

Comment: PAT doesn't seem to work when executing as part of a release. It works fine when I run it in powershell, but when I run it as part of a release I get some html back representing a login page.

Comment: Hmm, weird, even when you pass in a PAT as a parameter to the script it doesn't work? Are you running this in a private agent or a hosted agent?

Comment: It's a hosted agent (Azure Pipelines)

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue. Were considered two options, the same as you have been trying.

1. System.AccessToken
2. PAT

Problem was solved by putting PAT into a KeyVault and using it as a basic auth token for REST API call in a pipeline.

My suggestion is that it seems expected and right behavior. Why do I think so? From Azure DevOps point of view there are two levels in our case Organization's level and Project's level. You can notice the difference by URI that were used:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$($poolId)/agents?api-version=5.1"

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/$($project)/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1
```

From security point of view it's a bad practice, let entities from lower layers, which is project in our case, access and manipulate on the higher layer, which is organization in our case.

As a conclusion I would say that SystemToken and PAT in essence have slightly different nature, one is devoted for agent, and another for one's personal profile.